# Raspberry Pi IFTTT DO Button

Tags: linux, get, raspberry-pi, http-post, ifttt

I recently put together a Raspberry Pi garage door opener and it seems to be working well at this point.  I used [this](http://dhowdy.blogspot.com/2015/10/opening-garage-door-from-internet.html) as a reference and used his scripts and webpage with slight fixes/modifications.  I can now log into the site I'm hosting from the pi with Apache2 and open and close my door and view my webcam stream.  I am using DuckDNS and port forwarding port 80 to my pi currently.

What I would like to do next is set up IFTTT Maker Channel integration with the goal of using a DO Button to control the door from my Android Wear watch.  The problem is I don't know how to set up the pi to receive an HTTP request from [IFTTT.](https://ifttt.com/channels/maker/actions/1600703425-make-a-web-request)

Essentially what I need to learn how to do is have the pi listen for this request and run a script (setting GPIO pin 17 to high for a half second).  Presumably once I figure this out I would also be able to use Tasker/AutoVoice for Google Now integration.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out and want to post my limited knowledge answer for anyone looking to do the same, it was actually easier than I was making it.

I had a couple of problems from the start

1. My whole html root folder requires a password
2. I didn't understand what a GET request was doing in this instance
3. My script files weren't working properly

Here's how I was able to correct these issues and get it working

1. Send the username/password in the GET request, not extremely secure, but oh well:`http://user:password@address.org/file.php`
2. With the basic GET request it appears to just basically "load" the URL given as if you typed it in a browser address bar and hit enter, this means that if my script file is working correctly it should run the script
3. I corrected my script files

Comment: Congratulations you have just opened your garage door to any hacker that cares to capture your traffic. I hope for their own sake people don't get tempted to do the same! Please research OAUTH instead of you want to do a proper job.

Comment: +1 @RumburaK. There are many ways of securing your server. Token based authentication could be the fastest way to get there, though less secure.